# Send any kind of message to Facebook friend through graph API with privacy SELF

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need to send a message, may be any possible message in Facebook, to a friend through an app i created. I want to invite some of my friends to a private poll. En some other friends to an other private poll.

Now I do the following with the Facebook graph api:

```
$array = array(
  'message' => $user->getName() . ' invited you to join ' . $poll->getName(),
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com/poll/' . $poll->getId(),
  'privacy' => "{'value':'SELF'}",
);
$fb->api('/[facebook_friend_id]/feed','POST',$array);
```

But when this is send from my application the message on my friends wall will be visible to everyone. But I only want this friend to fill in this poll, and not anyone else.

I found that the parameter of privacy doesn't work when a message is send through an application. I don't want to use the javascript SDK, because the layout and the implemention don't fit the expectations for our app.

So we only need a, only server-side, way to send a message or notification to a friend which only my friend and I can see. All the answers I found were like two years old, so a lot happend during that time.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Facebook Timeline privacy works; the visibility of content on someone's timeline is determined by the user whose Timeline it is, not the user who posts it.

You can't post to someone else's timeline and choose the privacy.

Comment: But what can I do to send a message (doesn't matter what kind of) to a friend that only he sees. Maybe a notification of app request or something, but those have to go through a dialog and I don't want that.

Comment: The [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) is the best option for 1-1 messages initiated by your app